# Which one is best CSV or JSON in order to import big data (PHP)

Tags: php, json, performance, csv

I'm trying to get a big number of data (about 3M rows) and I have only two options to do that.

1. Call an API then recover the 3M JSON objects.
2. Import a CSV file containing the 3M rows.

I didn't test any of these solutions yet to tell which one is best in terms of speed.

Comment: CSV, it's a lot easier to read the file row by row, or use LOAD DATA INFILE so that it doesn't exceed PHP memory limits

Comment: Thanks Mark, LOAD DARA INFILE sounds like a great solution to me.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you want to retrieve **simple data** as lists or rows with some columns the option #2 is the good one, you can read below a set of advantages and disadvantages:

**Pros**

- **Less bandwidth** needed because JSON needs more syntax characters to keep the format while CSV is as simple as use a character separator
- **Process data is faster** because only needs to split by the separator character while JSON needs to interpret the syntax
- Big data technology as **Hadoop has an integrated parse for CSV format** while needs a specific function for parse JSON (for example using Hive language).

**Cons**

- Unstructured data and more difficult to be read by humans
- You have to take care as separator character cannot appear in data fields.

If the data will contain **complex data** as tuples, arrays and structures JSON are better because:

- Keeps a clear and **structured format**
- **Doesn't repeat data** to reference it because one label could contain multiple data.

Comment: Thanks Miguel, I guess I'll go for CSV, I wanted a simple application, where you can only hit a button, and the application will contact the API to get the JSON data, but in the other hand, it demands more execution time (because I have to paginate the JSON data, decode it, ...). I think I'll allow a CSV import and I'll make use of the LOAD DATA INFILE as Mark mentioned before. Speed is more important than simplicity I guess.

Comment: Another important pro: CSV lists can be parsed sequentially, keeping memory usage rather constant. A JSON object has to be parsed and loaded into memory all at once, which might be a problem at certain sizes.

Comment: jsonlines solves the memory issue somewhat
https://jsonlines.org/